# How to get By object from WebElement object in java

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How to get `By` object from `WebElement` object in Java.

I have defined a `WebElement` in a different class, in test plan i want to check whether the `WebElement` is available in the page or not. To have a better coding convention i want to avoid hard coding the `By`.

Comment: It makes me inclined to believe that using that convention you're going to face a lot of `StaleElementReferenceException` cases.

Answer (score -2):

If you **MUST** use the WebElement in another class, a way to reuse the element is declaring itself as a static one:

```java
public static WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("someId"));
```

Comment: I think the question is asking for the other way around : given WebElement, how to get By.